# Getting undeclared function and undefined symbol errors with rand_r when compiling a multithread C program on Windows

Tags: c, multithreading, random, pthreads, srand

I am creating many threads and each one should output a random number.

I know that `srand()` with `rand` is not thread-safe and indeed all the output numbers are the same.

So I tried to use `rand_r` but I get the following error on my Windows terminal

```
main.c:47:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rand_r'; did you mean 'rand'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 result= ( (rand_r(&seed) % (high+1-low) ) + low);
            ^~~~~~
            rand
main.c: In function 'customerServe':
main.c:333:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\allys\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSslADA.o:main.c:(.text+0xe): undefined 
reference to `rand_r'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\allys\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSslADA.o:main.c:(.text+0x41c): 
undefined reference to `rand_r'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thank you

Comment: rand_s on windows?

Comment: yes, I installed MinGW for gcc

Comment: you need to define _POSIX_C_SOURCE before you stdlib include, did you do it? you may provide the code in your post...

Comment: `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw from the post tags that you are using the "pthreads" library which stands for POSIX threads. Therefore this project cannot be run on Windows since it does not support the "lpthread" flag on your system.

If you insist on working on a Windows machine, you could use something like [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/) which lets the developer work on an **Ubuntu terminal from windows**. While having access to an Ubuntu-like system where the lpthreads library is supported, you can move on with your project. Another possible solution could be using docker to compile & run your project on an isolated ubuntu environment but this is kind of an overkill.

Let me know if this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to specify a late enough Posix source to avoid this warning, e.g.:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c11 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L pi.c -o pi -lm -lpthread
```